# Static Caching Per Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, static, authorization

I'm looking for a way to cache methods I've created through reflection, on a base type

```
public class AuthorizedDbContext : DbContext
{
    Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _filterMap;
    DbAuthorizationOptions _authOptions;

    public AuthorizedDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CreateGenericFilterMap()
    {
        var genericFilterCache = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        foreach (var entityType in this.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(e => e.ClrType))
        {
            var genericMethod = typeof(QueryFilterExtensions).GetExtensionMethodFor(typeof(DbContext))
                .Where(x => x.Name == nameof(QueryFilterExtensions.Filter))
                .Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                //TODO switch this to single and filter properly
                .First();

            genericFilterCache[entityType] = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
        }

        return genericFilterCache;
    }
}
```

I have this method `CreateGenericFilterMap()` which generates functions for filtering generically based on the existing entity types.   Since AuthorizedDbContext is a base class I cannot Store these methods statically.

I was thinking about adding them into the ServicesContainer so I can request them, but I'm not sure if that is proper since you are not suppose to use your DI container directly.

This seem's like a common problem, does anyone have a good way to cache objects for the lifetime of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold a private static dictionary of type and filterMaps in your base class. Like the following:

```
public class AuthorizedDbContext : DbContext
{
    Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _filterMap;
    DbAuthorizationOptions _authOptions;

    private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>> _cache;

    static AuthorizedDbContext() => _cache = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>>();

    public AuthorizedDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> CreateGenericFilterMap()
    {
        var genericFilterCache = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
        foreach (var entityType in this.Model.GetEntityTypes().Select(e => e.ClrType))
        {
            var genericMethod = typeof(QueryFilterExtensions).GetExtensionMethodFor(typeof(DbContext))
                .Where(x => x.Name == nameof(QueryFilterExtensions.Filter))
                .Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod && x.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                //TODO switch this to single and filter properly
                .First();

            genericFilterCache[entityType] = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
        }

        return _cache[GetType()] = genericFilterCache;
    }

    public Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> GetCache() => _cache[GetType()];
}
```

This will work because **GetType** will return the most derived type.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this before, so +1, I want something a bit cleaner than that, but I may find that this is the only way.

Comment: @johnny5, I can not really think of another way. I was about recommending the use of [Weak Table](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/The-ConditionalWeakTable-in-NET), but that only add dynamic functionality to objects, and in your case you need it for types

Comment: I might just make a singleton in the DI which will centralize my cache,  but I don’t want to make that a dependency so I think I’ll just use the way you provided